# Why I can't open a page in Internet Explorer, but it opens okay in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

I can open the above file in Firefox,but not in Internet Explorer. I don't have problems opening other pages in IE.

What could be the reason? I've checked, and it's not a proxy issue.

Comment: Commenting after your update... so when you open the above link in Firefox I assume it displays all the code. When you open it in IE, are you being prompted to download the file (as I mention in my answer below), or is nothing happening at all? E.g. a timeout, or a 404 etc...

Answer (score 6):

It's not that you can't open it, just that Firefox elects to display the JavaScript file (in this case jQuery), whereas Internet Explorer opts to download it instead.

If you aren't even seeing the download prompt when opening it in Internet Explorer, check the proxy settings are configured the same as Firefox.